# Add a 3d shape to an existing rgl object : alphashape3d

Tags: r, 3d, rgl, vegan

I have done this ordination analysis on a species dataset using `metaMDS()` from the 'vegan' package. I am using more than one dimension so I thought it would be nice display three of these dimensions in a 3d plot. The 'vegan' package has some 3d functionality but the results are not very clear. It can display this "spider" using the `orglspider()` function which is kind of nice but still not very clear. I rather have something like 'ordihull' but than as a 3d graph. Using the 'alphashape3d' package I can get this done. It allows me to draw a 3d shape exactly as I need it. The problem is that I need 3 of these shapes plotted in the same frame. I tried `"add=T"` but this doesn't work. I think I might have to change the way the second and third shapes are called, but I have no idea how to do this. Here is an example of what I have tried so far:

```
### Load the packages
require(vegan)
require(alphashape3d)

### Create some data
a <- c(0.5654292, 0.1960973, 0.0000000, 0.2536315, 0.1960973, 0.4658166, 0.3315565, 0.6865024, 0.7044823, 0.4385855)
b <- c(0.7093823, 0.2409255, 0.3269156, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.3269156, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.4625978)
c <- c(0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.1022538, 0.4618177, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.0000000)
d <- c(0.00000000, 0.16692171, 0.00000000, 0.22649864, 0.09400543, 0.42456471, 0.79331157, 0.72986751, 0.93837435, 0.65106335)
loc <- c("U", "U", "U", "A", "A", "U", "A", "A", "A", "U")

data <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)

#### Run the mds analysis to obtain the points that should be plotted
mdsB <- metaMDS(data, distance = "bray", autotransform = FALSE, trace = 0,k=3)

### Split the points in the mds object up into two groups
mdsBA <- mdsB
mdsBU <- mdsB

mdsBA$points <- mdsBA$points[which(loc=='A'), ]
mdsBU$points <- mdsBU$points[which(loc=='U'), ]

### Create the 3d shape just like the ordihull function does for 2d shapes
ashape3d.A <- ashape3d(unique(as.matrix(mdsBA$points[,1:3])), alpha = 1.19)
ashape3d.U <- ashape3d(unique(as.matrix(mdsBU$points[,1:3])), alpha = 1.19)

### plot the first shape and try to add the second one. 
plot(ashape3d.A,bycom=TRUE,tran=0.2,shininess=0, col="lightgoldenrod")
plot(ashape3d.U,bycom=TRUE,tran=0.2,shininess=0, col="lightgoldenrod", add=T)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I probably should have waited with posting my question as I have found an answer myself. I solved the problem by using a different package to create the convex hulls for which the `add=T` part actually did work. I used the "geometry" package as follows:

```
library("geometry")
A <- mdsBA$points[,1:3]
F <- mdsBU$points[,1:3]

A.surf <- t(convhulln(A))
U.surf <- t(convhulln(U))

rgl.triangles(A[A.surf,1],A[A.surf,2],A[A.surf,3],col="lightgoldenrod",alpha=0.5, add=T)
rgl.triangles(U[U.surf,1],U[U.surf,2],U[U.surf,3],col="lightgoldenrod",alpha=0.5, add=T)
```